# WCF Service Unexpected Exception on Endpoint

Tags: wcf, endpoint

We created WCF services hosted on various windows services.  During consumption of the WCF service by another windows service, initially everything goes successfully. But after continuous execution for a day, it suddenly throws the following exception:

The error message is `Could not find endpoint element with name 'MemoryClient' and contract 'IQueue.IRepository' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.`

The source of the exception `System.ServiceModel`

The stack trace of the exception:

`at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at EngineChannelFactory.RepositoryClient.CreateNewChannel(String strEndPoint)
THE TARGET SITE OF EXCEPTION   -> Void LoadChannelBehaviors(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint, System.String)`

The problem is, it is consuming this same end point for some time. Once the service restarts, the issue is resolved. Has anyone faced this issue? This is happening on Windows 2003 64 Bit Server, where .NET 3.5 is installed. Has someone said if this is an environment issue, and was fixed in .NET 3.5 SP1?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just ran into the same thing. Did you ever figure it out?